# node red function and export to CSV

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have the raspberry pi and sense hat.  I wish to extract acceleration z,y,x,Temperature and Pressure and time to csv.  However, the code I've written does not do what i want it to do.  I was expecting the data to leave the function in an array but the debug window shows them as separate objects.  How do i get acceleration z,y,x and time to leave as one array so i can export to CSV?

```
    29/03/2017, 17:17:23node: abf1ef08.31a6f
msg : Object
object
payload: 0.9487
_msgid: "ae0db049.020f6"
29/03/2017, 17:17:23node: abf1ef08.31a6f
msg : Object
object
payload: 0.2781
_msgid: "ae0db049.020f6"
29/03/2017, 17:17:23node: abf1ef08.31a6f
msg : Object
object
payload: 0.1491
_msgid: "ae0db049.020f6"
29/03/2017, 17:17:23node: abf1ef08.31a6f
msg : Date
"Wed Mar 29 2017 16:17:25 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Here's the function code :

```
var msgAccelZ,msgAccelX,msgAccelY,msgTemperature,msgPressure,msgCurrentTime;
if (msg.topic === 'motion') {
    msgAccelZ = { payload: msg.payload.acceleration.z, };
    msgAccelX = { payload: msg.payload.acceleration.x, };
    msgAccelY = { payload: msg.payload.acceleration.y, };
} else if (msg.topic === 'environment') {
    msgTemperature = { payload: msg.payload.temperature };
    msgPressure = { payload: msg.payload.pressure };
}
msgCurrentTime = new Date();
return [ [msgAccelZ, msgAccelX, msgAccelY,msgCurrentTime] ,[msgTemperature, msgPressure, msgCurrentTime] ];
```

Answer (score 1):

A Function needs to return a message object, not just a raw value.

By convention, you'd put the data you want to return under `msg.payload`:

```
msg.payload = [ [msgAccelZ, msgAccelX, msgAccelY,msgCurrentTime] ,[msgTemperature, msgPressure, msgCurrentTime] ];
return msg;
```

The documentation for the Function node explains in more detail: http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions